# Angular 9 how to fix export 'CDK_TABLE' was not found in '@angular/cdk/table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Just migrated from 8 to 9. Done everything step by step, I am using angular material, migrated it as well, changed all paths from **@angular/material** -> **@angular/material/table** . Now when i run ng serve, i get this error  :

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/material/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/table.js 55:23-32
"export 'CDK_TABLE' was not found in '@angular/cdk/table'
```

Package.json :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "9.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/core": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/material": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^9.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-server": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.901.0",
    "@angular/router": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/service-worker": "9.0.7",
    "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^1.0.2",
    "@ngmodule/material-carousel": "^0.6.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^9.1.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "^3.0.1",
    "@squadette/hammerjs": "^2.1.0-pre3",
    "@types/core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "express": "4.17.1",
    "firebase": "^7.6.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "http-status-codes": "^1.4.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "localstorage-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
    "m": "^1.5.6",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "^5.3.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "subsink": "^1.0.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.900.7",
    "@angular/cli": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "9.0.7",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "9.0.2",
    "@types/express": "4.17.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.5.9",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "13.9.2",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.5.2",
    "protractor": "5.4.3",
    "ts-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "ts-node": "8.7.0",
    "tslint": "6.1.0",
    "typescript": "3.7.5"
  }
```

How to fix this error ? I am using angular material table mostly with these imports :

```
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
```

Any of packages versions mismatch or another problem ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using `npm install @angular/cdk --save` should resolve this.

Comment: Why when i install this package it removes 1200 packages from node modules ?

Comment: removed 1273 packages, updated 2 packages and audited 1635 packages in 33.966s

Answer (score 5):

Stumbled on this too. Turns out the packages got de-synced somehow in `packages.json`.

Make sure you have latest version for all: 9.20 for `material` packages:

```
"@angular/material": "^9.2.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^9.2.0",
```

Also, update your `@angular` packages to 9.1.0 (command depends on your package manager).

Answer (score 1):

An important note is that most material components have individual paths now, so in case your imports looks like `import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material'` you should change them to `import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';` or `import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';`

As I have upgraded a project to v9 I can confirm that the other 3 imports (

```
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
```

) look ok.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Verify that in your package.json the

```
@angular/cdk
@angular material
```

are at the same version.

Mine on 07/08/2021 are at latest version:

```
"@angular/cdk": "^12.2.0",
"@angular/material": "^12.2.0",
```

Have a nice day.